# How to solve this error in Ecilipse about Marketplace?

Tags: eclipse-marketplace

I got this error not resolving I tried in many ways

Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null

To resolve this issue