In eclipse after updating the market place, I am unable to access the marketplace

Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.IMarketplaceServiceLocator.getCatalogService()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.service.ServiceHelper.getMarketplaceServiceLocator()" is null

I tried setting to manual or direct in network but still it did not work

Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74613815, but that has no answers either.

@Rup That is the same error message, but without details it is not possible to say that it is a duplicate.
